# SSRS column group displays data on unique rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a data set where i'm using a table to display Name, Radio #, and Unit # information in SSRS tablix. As some of the groups have 60+ members, i thought it would be better to expand the tables into 4 columns repeating those detail fields instead of displaying a 3 page long skinny table. In the SQL i used a row count%4 function to assign a "position" number 0-3 for each name. If i create a table with the detail members above and then add a parent column group on position, i get the tables repeated as i want but each name/radio/unit appears on a unique row. I've tried several different ways of grouping rows/columns but always seem to get this staggered table (with only name/radio to make it easier to digest): [sample_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq6I3.png)

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I've really searched quite a bit before putting this in but it's probably the case that if i knew what to search, i wouldn't be putting this question in. So if you'd rather tell me what to search i can do that too. :)

Answer (score 0):

SSRS will display a row in the table for each row returned from the dataset, this is normal behaviour for data to display.

One way to get what you want is to create a query which has all the information form your column headings in one row, probably with a pivot or similar.

Or you could just display your columns in separate tables.